# Returning json from northwind db with asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to return a json object from my controller to my view. i'm using the the northwind db for testing and used used dbfirst for creating the model. from what i understand i have to use anonymous types for json. however it doesn't work. and i don't what's the best approach to debuging.

(with the manualy generated list i commented out it works...)

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        ////List<int> result = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5 };
        ////return Json(result);   

        using (var db = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            var results = from Cust in db.Customers
                          select new
                          {
                              CustomerAddress = Cust.Address,
                              CustomerCity = Cust.City,
                              CustomerCompanyName = Cust.CompanyName
                          };

            return Json(results);

            Console.Write(results);
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<input id="btn" type="button" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $.post("/Northwind/GetData", null, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you try : `return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: I know. not important. AllowGet is for your data that is in alert.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Didn't know that. But sadly doesn't change anything.

Comment: Debugged it? Does results have data?

Comment: And also, you can handle js errors with browser's tools.

Comment: Yeah I set a breakpoint and the "results view" looks like that:[0] = { CustomerAddress = "aa", CustomerCity = "aa", CustomerCompanyName = "aa" }

Comment: Did some debugging and found that i get a: "InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Answer (score 0):

Your context has been disposed, use this:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    var db = new NorthwindEntities()

    var results = from Cust in db.Customers
                      select new
                      {
                          CustomerAddress = Cust.Address,
                          CustomerCity = Cust.City,
                          CustomerCompanyName = Cust.CompanyName
                      };

    return Json(results.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try materialize expression first before sending it back ( simply invoke toArray)